# Docker build: Extentions not loading via apk: exif, gd, pdo_mysql, pecl-redis. What can I do to fix my dockerfile? From php:7.4-fpm-alpine

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I'm using `FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine` as my image and trying to load everything I need with `RUN add apk`, everything seems to build correctly, but some things are not actually working when I try to use them.

Searching around I seem to have found workarounds for all of them, but now my dockerfile take a long long time to build. I'm just learning Docker and on a super slow internet connection, so this is not ideal.

I'm wondering if I am doing something wrong? Or if I can make my dockerfile more efficient. -- Thanks!

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

RUN apk update \
    &&  apk add curl php7-curl php7-json php7-tokenizer php7-mbstring php7-exif php7-fileinfo \
    php7-bcmath php7-dom php7-session php7-simplexml php7-ctype 



#* PDO EXIF    The apk is not working!
# RUN apk add php7-exif
RUN docker-php-ext-install exif

#* EXT-GD      The apk is not working!
# RUN apk add php7-gd
RUN apk add libpng libpng-dev && docker-php-ext-install gd && apk del libpng-dev

#* PDO MYSQL   The apk is not working!
# RUN apk add php7-pdo php7-pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

#* EXT-REDIS   The apk is not working!
# RUN apk php7-pecl-redis
RUN apk add --no-cache pcre-dev $PHPIZE_DEPS \
    && pecl install redis \
    && docker-php-ext-enable redis.so

#* Get permissions right
RUN apk add shadow && usermod -u 1000 www-data && groupmod -g 1000 www-data
```

Answer (score 0):

The official php Docker Image uses a [self compiled version of php](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/b6fd2f70018163227f0f18f3ba1fa4d70e6d929e/7.4/alpine3.12/fpm/Dockerfile#L122) which is not compatible with the php included in the Alpine package repository. You have two choices to solve this:

- Either use `docker-php-ext-install` and `docker-php-ext-enable` for everything and no `apk add php*` or
- Use the Alpine base image with the php from the package repository.

A long build time does not necessarily mean your internet connection is to slow. Compiling `exif`, `gd`, `pdo_mysql` and `redis` takes it time, too. Check your bandwidth and CPU usage while building the image and then you know for sure where your bottle neck is. To speed things up you can efficiently cache layers by first installing dependencies with apk, then composer, pip, etc. and finally adding your code.